# estructura para imprimir desde java script

Tags: javascript, php

aun no he realizado la estructura de mi código, no sé si me podría apoyar en poder utilizar la función de javascript widows.print() en el cual manda la prevista para visualización de impresión para imprimir la hoja ficia, como cuando mandamos a imprimir un documento por el explorador, pero esta funcion imprime lo que este en pantalla, alguien me puede apoyar como aplicar dicha aplicación, si yo tengo un pdf generado y que puedo guardarlo en mi servidor, he leido que con embed se podría pero no tengo ni idea de comor ealizar.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué quieres *imprimir*? Y cuando dices *imprimir*, ¿te refieres a la consola o a una hoja física en una impresora? Por favor, haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta, incluyendo lo que has intentado o investigado, mediante un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: La función `widows.printf` no existe.  De hecho en google translate me dice que es `viudas.printf` su traducción literal.  Espero que no estés en ese colectivo y si es así tienes todo mi apoyo. Dicho esto, si te refieres a [window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/print) entonces vale, te saldrá el diálogo para imprimir. Si estas visualizando un PDF puedes descargarlo en lugar de intentar imprimirlo con el javascript. Si quieres descargarlo puedes enviarlo directamente desde PHP con las cabeceras adecuadas sin javascript.